# 401 error when accessing OpenAI using httr2 library

Tags: r, curl, http-status-code-401, httr2

Error:
Error in `req_perform()`:
! HTTP 401 Unauthorized.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

```
#Libraries used (probably overkill): 
library(httr2)
library(wordcloud)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(wordcloud2)
library(tm)
library(readr)
library(pdftools)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(stopwords)
```

```
url_base <-"https://api.openai.com/v1/"
prompt <- "Please tell me a dad joke"
```

Input code:
model_type<-"gpt-3.5-turbo"

```
body <- list(model    = model_type,
             messages = list(list(role = "user", 
             content = prompt)))

response<-request(url_base) |>
req_url_path_append("chat/completions") |>
req_auth_bearer_token(token = api_key) |>
req_headers("Content-Type" = "application/json") |> 
req_user_agent("JustADude @justadude") |> 
req_body_json(body)  |> 
req_perform()
```

req_dry_run() output:

```
POST /v1/chat/completions HTTP/1.1
Host: api.openai.com
User-Agent: JustADude @justadude
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
Authorization: <REDACTED>
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 92

{"model":"gpt-3.5-turbo","messages":[{"role":"user","content":"Please tell me a dad joke"}]}
```

Any recommendations for fixing the error?  I've looked into the OpenAI Reference material (https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference) but not seeing the error on my part.  Thank you for any recommendations on fixing the error.

Comment: That error would point to your `api_key` being incorrect. https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/error-codes Try generating a new one. Or are you able to validate it in some other context? What's the full response you get if you look at the `resp_raw()` of your `req_perform()`. Is there more information in the body of the message?

Comment: Runnng resp_raw() on the output above provides the following: response %>% resp_raw()
Error in resp$status_code : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: Also, tried key on code that was working and it is still working, so no idea why the above is jacked up...  so weird...  here's the output of the working code... and the above was working... sigh... <httr2_response>
POST https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions
Status: 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Body: In memory (435 bytes)
> response %>% resp_raw()
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
date: Thu, 14 Sep 2023 14:32:05 GMT
content-type: application/json
access-control-allow-origin: *
cache-control: no-cache, must-revalidate
openai-model: gpt-3.5-turbo-0613...

Comment: I guess with `httr2` it throws errors by default which is annoying. Try `... |> req_error(is_error=function(...) FALSE) |>  req_perform() |> resp_raw()` just after the `req_body_json()` part

Comment: That did it!  It was my api_key... turns out I was stomping on it with an old one... ugh... got to clean up my code better... thanks a ton!!!!!!!  Your error debug for the win!!! |> req_error(is_error=function(...) FALSE) |>  req_perform() |> resp_raw() just after the req_body_json()